# Restore %APPDATA% to AppData/Roaming folder

Tags: windows, windows-10

After installing Windows, I originally moved the 3 AppData subfolders to my external harddrive, but I quickly changed my mind and restored them (clicking the restore button). Now `%APPDATA%` is incorrectly pointing to AppData/LocalLow. It should be pointing to AppData/Roaming. I found this by running `set` in Command Promt. How do I restore it to default settings?

I am specifically on Windows 10, but I assume this is the same for all versions of Windows since 7.

Comment: Please explain why you are downvoting, thank you.

Comment: You have set the location, to your desired location, by using `Properties > Location` i presume?  You also have verified the registry points to the correct location? `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\AppData` is the key you are interested in

Comment: @Ramhound it has no Location anymore. See http://i.stack.imgur.com/nSTX2.png. I have just tried changing the environment variable `APPDATA` back using `set APPDATA [mypath]`, but that did not persist. I'll try the registery key instead.

Comment: I thought you said its location was incorrectly pointing to AppData/LocalLow`?  The screenshot you just provided clearly indicates its location is correct.  The system variable, %APPDATA%, I presume is the only thing that isn't correct (and I trust your comment that its pointing to the wrong folder).

Comment: Yes, `%appdata%` is pointing to AppData/LocalLow. That screenshot is of Roaming's properties. Isn't that what you're refering to? I also tried changing the registery key, but it doesn't persist either. Edit: actually, it seems to persist, but it has no effect.

Comment: So you changed the registry key, and it reverted back, to what value specifically?

Comment: My memory is a bit fuzzy on that, I did that somewhere in November, today I just found out something went wrong. I moved the 3 subfolders by clicking the move button, see http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvn2o.png (this one is properly set up and working), then I decided to move them back. Something went wrong there and Roaming got moved back, as in, the location is correct, but %APPDATA% is somehow pointing to LocalLow instead of Roaming.

Comment: The simplest solution.  Create a new user.  Take ownership of those files and folders in AppData on the old profile in order to transfer your application settings.

Comment: That worked. Thank you! Feel free to write it into an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Check `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Volatile Environment` registry key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the issue was user-related, a newly created user did not have the issue. (Thanks Ramhound for the suggestion)

I simply created a new Administrator user and removed the old one. Do keep in mind that this will delete all user specific files for the old user (Documents, Downloads, AppData, etc.), so back them up.