# Is it possible to FIX the %AppData%/Roaming after moving it to different location

Tags: windows-10, boot, appdata

I moved `%AppData%\Roaming\` to a different drive and realized afterward that Windows somehow lost access to `%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\` (couldn't read and write), so I lost startup items and many links in the Start Menu (it was initially working after the move and all other apps are working fine). I decided to revert this action, but it didn't help (security settings are the same as before).

Is there any chance to fix this, without reinstalling the OS, such as an automatic troubleshooter that would detect something wrong with permissions and fix it?

Comment: Similar to https://superuser.com/questions/1023201/restore-appdata-to-appdata-roaming-folder

Comment: @spikey_richie I saw it. So creating new user would help me? Can I keep all settings of programs? In example can I create new user and then copy content of %AppData%/Roaming to new user? I would like to keep everything.

Comment: @user1203429 You have a couple of issues going on: `%AppData%\Roaming` is not a valid directory and is the reason you're experiencing issues. `%AppData%` is a variable that points to `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming` _(just as `%LocalAppData%` points to `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local`)_, with `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Roaming` not being a valid directory _(it doesn't exist)_. The second problem is I'm almost certain `%AppData%` contains hardlinks, and if it does, it's why it's not intended to ever be moved, since doing so would break those hardlinks, resulting in a malformed user profile.

Comment: _Cont'd..._ @user1203429 A malformed user profile is not possible to fix in an efficient manner, so the only fix would be to create a new user profile _(e.g. create a new user)_ and copy over files from the old one. While many files and directories within `%AppData%` and `%LocalAppData%` can be copied over to a new user profile, not all can be _(doing so would result in another malformed user profile)_. It's generally safe to move 3rd party directories within either over, however for those files generated by Windows when a user profile is created, leave them be & either re-sync or re-customize

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the post itself contains errors that will block any meaningful answer. See the comment by JW0914 below the poster's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was messed up registry `%AppData%` path issues (screenshot below). I manually edited the registry and restarted - Start Menu and startup items are back to normal.
[image: Screenshot]

I will be moving everything from inside `%AppData%/Roaming` to another drive and create symlinks for them, except for `..\Microsoft\` location.

Comment: You have a couple of issues going on: `%AppData%\Roaming` is not a valid directory and is the reason you're experiencing issues. `%AppData%` is a location variable that points to `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming` _(just as `%LocalAppData%` points to `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local`)_, with `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Roaming` not being a valid directory _(it doesn't exist)_. The second problem is I'm almost certain `%AppData%` contains hardlinks, and if it does, it's why it's not intended to ever be moved, since doing so would break those hardlinks, resulting in a malformed user profile.