# I cannot change the environment variable of %APPDATA%

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables

Long ago I changed the `%APPDATA%` default path from `C:Users\Username\Appdata` to `D:Users\Username\Appdata` (I don't remember how). Now my `D:` hardrive crash and is no longer operational. I tried going to System, Advanced System settings then Environment Variables but I could not find APPDATA either on user variables or system variable. So I created one that would point to my `C:` drive, but when I use `echo %APPDATA%` it still point to my `D:` drive. So I try `setx APPDATA "(cdrive location)"` but the APPDATA still point to the `D:` drive. I am at my wits end.

Comment: In the registry, under the keys, HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders, what are the values for the value name, AppData?

Comment: it would be good to, don't think it will solve your immediate issue, just make sure all the folders exist on the C: drive

Comment: indeed it didn't solve my problem. in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell` i changed all the value that was pointing to `D:` to `C:`:. Yet echo `%APPDATA%` still point to `D:`

Comment: read [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1572848/is-it-possible-to-fix-the-appdata-roaming-after-moving-it-to-different-locatio), particularly JW0914's comment, there maybe more than you bargain for when moving %APPDATA% Folder.

Comment: Thank njc. i switched to a local account and the appdata point to the correct location.